# Why does the following RegionPlot command not evaluate?

Tags: plotting, units

I have some trouble understanding the `RegionPlot` command. I have defined the following input

```
Clear["Global`*"]

volume[R_, d_] := Pi R^2 d

atomNumber[R_, d_, n_] := 2*n*volume[R, d]

\[Gamma]Fn[x_] := 
 2/x^2 (1 - Exp[-x^2] (BesselI[0, x^2] + BesselI[1, x^2]))

\[Eta]Eval[\[Lambda]_, d_, R_, rc_, n_] := 
 UnitConvert[\[Lambda]*((atomNumber[R, d, n])^2/d^2) \[Gamma]Fn[
    R/(Sqrt[2] rc)] (1 - Exp[-d^2/(4*rc^2)])]

\[Del]Fn[\[Omega]_, m_] := 
 UnitConvert[Sqrt[Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"]/(\[Omega]*m)]]

coherence[\[Omega]_, d_, R_, rc_, \[Lambda]_, n_, T_, m_] := 
 UnitConvert[
  4*\[Eta]Eval[\[Lambda], d, R, rc, n]*T*(\[Del]Fn[\[Omega], m])^2]
```

with units

```
Subscript[m, 0] = Quantity[1, "AtomicMassUnit"]
R = Quantity[3.6, "Micrometers"]
d = Quantity[0.25, "Millimeters"]
n = Quantity[176.2 * 10^(27), "Meters"^(-3)]
rc = Quantity[10^(-7), "Meters"]
\[Lambda] = Quantity[10^(-17), "Seconds"^(-1)]
T = Quantity[350, "Femtoseconds"]
m = Quantity[6, "AtomicMassUnit"]
\[Omega]Paper = Quantity[40, "Terahertz"]
```

When I evaluate my functions separately, everything works as intended:

```
coherence[\[Omega]Paper, d, R, rc, \[Lambda], n, T, m]
Out: 2.28009*10^-15

coherence[\[Omega]Paper, d, R, rc, \[Lambda], n, T, m] < 1
Out: True
```

I want to evaluate the above inequality for a range of values for $(\lambda, r_c)$.
So: Define an input range for $\lambda$ and for $r_c$ $\Rightarrow$ evaluate `coherence(input) < 1` $\Rightarrow$ plot all points $(\lambda, r_c)$ for which this is true.

For that, I use the following `RegionPlot` command:

```
RegionPlot[
 Evaluate[coherence[\[Omega]Paper Quantity[40, "Terahertz"], 
    d Quantity[1/4, "Millimeters"], R Quantity[18/5, "Micrometers"], 
    rc, \[Lambda], n Quantity[1762*10^(26), "Meters"^(-3)], 
    T Quantity[350, "Femtoseconds"], 
    m Quantity[6, "AtomicMassUnit"]] < 1], {rc, 
  Quantity[10^-9, "Meters"], Quantity[10^-1, "Meters"]}, {\[Lambda], 
  Quantity[10^-10, ("Seconds")^-1], Quantity[10^-1, ("Seconds")^-1]}]
```

However, the code doesn't even run and the notebook stops after a while. What is the issue with this code?

My thoughts:

- the numbers are too small (I can't change the numbers -> are there alternative programs to plot?)
- there is some issue with my Mathematica version
  **strong text**

Comment: On my machine, v12.2Win7-x64, the `RegionPlot` command results in a kernel crash.

Comment: Ok but why? As outlined, when I evaluate the functions separately, everything works as intended. What other sites can I consult? Are there alternatives?

Comment: @Syed Put differently: Is there a way to define only certain tuples as input? So instead of plotting the full range, I only want to plot 10 values of $\lambda$: $10^{-n}$ for $n \in \{0, 1, ..., 10\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a workaround that at least produces output.  It produces a few error messages and took almost 1 minute to calculate, but it may be useful as a starting point.  Note that the scale is log-log.

```
$Version  (*  12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)  *)

RegionPlot[coherence[ωPaper, d, R,
    10^logrc  Quantity["Meters"],
    10^logλ  Quantity["Seconds"^-1],
    n, T , m ] < 1,
  {logrc, -9, -1},
  {logλ, -10, -1}] // Quiet
```

[image]

All error messages have been suppressed.  They are underflows caused by evaluating `Exp` with a large negative argument.  This is considered benign, since the exponential is subtracted from 1.

Another way to visualize the region by plotting the `coherence` as a 3D surface.  An array of about 1000 data points will produce a sufficiently smooth surface.  The data points can be generated and plotted like this

```
data = Flatten[
    Table[{logrc, log\[Lambda], coherence[\[Omega]Paper, d, R,
       10^logrc  Quantity["Meters"],
       10^log\[Lambda]  Quantity["Seconds"^-1],
       n, T , m ]},
     {logrc, -9, -1, .2},
     {log\[Lambda], -6, -1, .2}], 1]; // Quiet

ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

This plot has been cut off at z=1 in order to visualize the boundary for which `coherence == 1`.

The logarithmic scales in the above plots may be misleading.  A linear plot, such as the one below, shows that the surface is much steeper for small values of `rc` than it is for the larger values.  The following plot is `coherence` vs `rc` for $\lambda = 0.00002/\text{sec}$

```
data2 = Table[{10^logrc, coherence[\[Omega]Paper, d, R,
      10^logrc  Quantity["Meters"],
      2*^-5 /Quantity["Seconds"],
      n, T , m ]},
    {logrc, -8, -3, 0.025}]; // Quiet
ListLinePlot[data2, FrameLabel -> {"rc"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Upon reflection, I think I don't need to plot the full range of points to get some output. Is there a way to A) define e.g. 100 input tuples and B) evaluate the inequality for those 100 input tuples?

Comment: @LionCereals  When I get a blank plot I will often change the plot command to `Table` so I can see the what is really going on.  I did that on this one, to sort the units problem.  I'll add an example of using `Table` to my answer.  Thanks for accepting my answer, but accepting my workaround may discourage another who has the real answer.  Feel free to un-accept this workaround and wait to see if you get some really good answers.